# Is it complusory to pass instance to serializer in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a serialize`DeviceGroup` and a APIView class for posting devices into the group.

The serializer for `DeviceGroup` is

```
class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ['id','name']

class DevicesGroupsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        print('reqquest', request.data)
        print('token', token)
        device_group_instance = DeviceGroup.objects.get(token=token)
        for device_token in request.data['devices']:
            device = Device.objects.get(token=device_token, owner=request.user)
            device.group = device_group_instance
            device.save()
```

In above post function, is it compulsory to create a instance of serializer and check if serializer is valid then return the response.

The relation between Device and `DeviceGroup` is a device can be on only one group and a group can have multiple devices(list of device ids)

How should the post function be if i need to use `DeviceGroupSerializer` to post the list of devices? I did not understand this serializer and view part clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST framework is loosely coupled so you can bypass serializers.

However, depending on what you are doing, this may requires some work. Note that for POST you may perform some checks by yourself instead.

Tom Christies [post](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/api-performance-profiling-django-rest-framework/) on Django REST framework performances optimization illustrate how you can remove parts of the framework.

Comment: Can you show me a rough code on what else I have to do, please ?

Comment: This is not possible as it depends too much on what you are trying to do. Moreover, the link does give you more than enough to achieve that.